# Eclipse - General usage of hopping between multiple files

Tags: java, eclipse, file, user-controls, tabs

I have 3 projects in my eclipse and all are related. So I need to work on all files from all 3 projects.

What is the best way to switch between files? I keep opening files with Ctrl+Shift+R, search and open the files. But too many files pile up in the file tabs list and I again have to search within that file tabs list to get the file I need.

Am looking for something like the navigator for the File tabs list, instead of clicking the filetab list to search within already opened files.

Obviously, been using eclipse for a few months. So trying to find to do things in a better way.

Comment: I guess this helps a little bit. But anything like a fixed view for Ctrl+F6?

Comment: Ctrl+F6 is what I need, but as a Fixed View like a navigator, if anything exists.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, *Control-Shift-T* opens a dialog in which you can begin typing a class name. (On Mac, press *Command-Shift-T*).

When your class appears, double-click it.

This works whether the file is open or not, eliminating the need for you to stop to think about whether it's currently open.

**EDIT:**

You can get something similar by using Mylin. It allows you to filter the Navigator and Package Explorer views to show only the files you've touched as part of the current task. This may be different from the set currently open, but again, it eliminates the need for you to stop and think about whether a file is open. It also allows you to switch easily between contexts of different tasks, with different sets of relevant files.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But again it piles up the at the Files tab.

Comment: In terms of finding a document, why do you care, if there's an alternate mechanism to find the document? (BTW, are you already familiar with pressing the >> at the right of the file tabs?)

Comment: Yes, thats again multiple clicks. If I have the fixed view for the filestab, like a navigator, then I can keep that open and click on the file instead of searching and selecting.

Comment: If you use Mylin, you can filter the Navigator and Package Explorer views to show only the files you've touched as part of the current task. This may be different from the set currently open, but this could be a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

you could try alt+left arrow or right arrow or even bookmark this way you can just click from the book mark list 
here is [list](http://eclipse-tools.sourceforge.net/Keyboard_shortcuts_%283.0%29.pdf) of all eclipse shortcut

Comment: It goes in a sequence. if there are 40 files open, then I have to surf through the list.

Comment: I always do the bookmark when I have multiple files to work with and then use the alt+left or right arrow to jump back and forth or as you explained ctrl+shift+R is very good. I know it's not very easy and I like your question because I think it's something I would like to know if there is any easier way.